# Set theory: Function proof question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:C \to A$ and $g:B \to A$ be functions and assume that $g$ is bijective. Prove the following.

(a) There exists a function $h: C \to B$ such that $f=g \circ h$ if and only if $ran(f) \subset ran(g)$.

(b) Show that such an $h$ is unique.

For (a) I have proved the left to right side.

let $a \in A$ such that $f(c)=a$

$f(c)=(g \circ h)(c)$
since $h$ is a function, there exists some $b$ such that $h(c)=b$

$(g \circ h)(c)=g(b)=a$.

Thus $a \in ran(g)$

I have no clue on how to prove the reverse way and (b). Could you help me with this?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: it is the set of all images of f, isn't it?

Comment: @DHMO The range of $f$, I'd assume.

Comment: Do you really mean that $g:B\to A$ is bijective? I think you mean injective here (and then it's a bijection between $B$ and its range).

Comment: Yes the question states that $g$ is bijective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converse of (a), let $c\in C$ then $f(c)\in A=g(B)$ so there exists a unique $b\in B$ such that $g(b)=f(c)$. Define $h:C\rightarrow B$ as $h(c)=b$. This is a well defined map because of the uniqueness of $b$. Then $g(h(c))=g(b)=f(c)$ so $gh=f$. To show uniqueness, let there be another $j:C\rightarrow B$ such that $gj=f$. Then $gj=gh\Rightarrow j=h$ because $g$ is bijective.